# Computing integral in context of expectation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, normal-distribution, expected-value

Consider a random variable $S \ \sim \mathcal{N}(s, s^2 o^2T) $ for $s, o,T >0$

I want to compute $$E[(S-K)_+] =  \int_{K-s}^{\infty} \frac{1}{so\sqrt{2 \pi T}} (x+s-K)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2s^2o^2 T}} dx$$.

Consider the  integral: $$\int_{K-s}^{\infty} \frac{1}{so\sqrt{2 \pi T}} (s-K)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2s^2o^2T}}$$. How can I see that is evaluates to $
(s-K) \Phi(\frac{s-K}{s\sigma\sqrt{T)}})$